# cloudKit beta testing

Tags: ios, xcode, cloudkit

I'm trying to have beta testers to test my app using cloudKit works fine but the problem I cannot figure out how to hit the production (cloudKit) severs from my devices:

```
"<CKContainer: 0x170107080; containerID=<CKContainerID: 0x17003ed20; containerIdentifier=iCloud.com.xxxx.myCloudKitApp, containerEnvironment=\"Sandbox\">>"
```

Any of you knows how can I modify my devices or my xcode proyect to hit the production servers?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

When you sign your app for distribution it will automatically connect to the production database. There is no need to set this from code.

Comment: How can you do that for Mac app?